# what kind of variable/function/object is session("var") = "Value"

Tags: session, vbscript, policy

I am trying to make modifications to a vbscript that uses the line:
Session("Variable") = "MyVariable String"

This line requires it to be ran within a different program which is not available where I am doing my development. This line is NOT important to the development that I am doing and I just need it to NOT blow up with 'undefined variable session' when I am running with 'Option explicit'. What class, dictionary, variable type, or whatever do I need to create in order for that line to work without warnings/errors? I am currently just commenting them out, but when I copy and paste my code back in production I have to go back through and hope that I have uncommitted all of them back out. I'd rather just add a for instance "Set Session = New FooSomething" at the top of the code that will make it work and just remove that line when I add to production code. Thanks for your time.

Comment: The [`Session` object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524319%28v=vs.90%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) is part of the [tag:asp-classic] [object model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524664(v=vs.90).aspx) which is a server-side scripting language that harnesses [tag:vbscript]. You cannot use it directly in VBScript as it's a server-side technology that requires an IIS Web server with the ASP Handler installed to host it.

Comment: Use `TypeName` or `VarType` to get the type of a variable or object.